# How to remove the duplicate values in pandas df column by using keep parameter first & Last in the same column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df like below

## E.g Df

```
Index     a
0         1
1         1    
2         1
3         1
4         2
5         3           
6         4
7         5
8         6
9         7
10        7
11        7 
12        7
```

## What i required

I want to drop the duplicate value rows such that I want to use  `df.drop_duplicate (subset = 'a',keep = 'last')` for the Top duplicates and to use `df.drop_duplicate (subset = 'a',keep = 'first')` for the bottom duplicates.
Like below....

```
Index         a
    3         1
    4         2
    5         3           
    6         4
    7         5
    8         6
    9         7
```

I am sure that there will be some easy approach for the above problem.

Comment: How many are your top duplicates and bottom duplicates?

Comment: since I have to do this operation for list of csv files of more 10000 rows, i cannot specify it. But probably Top duplicates & Bottom duplicates < 1000 @MohitMotwani

Comment: I don't understand. By top duplicates  do you mean, the most duplicate values or the  duplicates in the top n rows?

Comment: @ponraj.rajesh can you explain the logic in brief for us and future readers? Thanks

Comment: the duplicates in the top n rows @MohitMotwani

Comment: what is your desired output

Comment: so if `n=4` : `pd.concat([df.drop(df.nlargest(4,'a').index).\
           drop_duplicates('a',keep='last'),df.nlargest(4,'a').drop_duplicates('a',keep='first')])` .. ??

Comment: @Jeril I have already mentioned in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
first = df.a.ne(df.a.shift(-1)).idxmax()
last = df.a.ne(df.a.shift(1))[::-1].idxmax()
df.loc[first:last,:]
```

**Output**

```
   a
3  1
4  2
5  3
6  4
7  5
8  6
9  7
```

**Details**

`first` and `last` will be used to compute the starting and final indices from the dataframe in order to obtain the expected output. The first `True` indices in both cases can be obtained using [`DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
x = df.a.ne(df.a.shift(-1))
print(x)

0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10    False
11    False
12     True
Name: a, dtype: bool

print(x.idxmax())
# 3
```

And for the last index:

```
y = df.a.ne(df.a.shift(1))[::-1]
print(y)

0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10    False
11    False
12     True
Name: a, dtype: bool

print(y.idxmax())
# 9
```

Answer (score 1):

from my understanding I think this what you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': np.random.randint(0, 50, 1000)})
df.head()
    values
0   26
1   6
2   4
3   21
4   45
df.shape
(1000, 1)
```

Assuming your top n rows is 500. First make a dataframe with top 500 rows and drop duplicates while keeping last and similarly for remaining rows while keeping first rows

```
top_n = 500
df_top = df.loc[:top_n].drop_duplicates(subset = 'values', keep='last')
df_bottom = df.loc[top_n:].drop_duplicates(subset = 'values', keep='first')
df_new = pd.concat([df_top, df_bottom])
df_new

df_new.shape
(100, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, It helps !!!!
But since i cannot able to specify the value 500 every time. Since it varies...@Mohit Motwani